# Change color of a date box based on time

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting

I'm new to SharePoint list and JSON.

I'm trying to get a date to change color if it is 12 months in the past.

Example date entered 01.01.2020 and today's date is 17.11.21, I want the date entered to change to red.

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use column JSON formatting for this requirement. Use below JSON code in the "Format this column" option for your date column:

```
{
   "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
   "elmType": "div",
   "txtContent": "@currentField",
   "style": {
      "color": "=if(@currentField + 31536000000 <= @now, '#ff0000', '')"
   }
}
```

**Output**:

[image]

**Documentation**: [Use column formatting to customize SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting)

Comment: Perfect thank you.